# Developing/Debugging .net Core 2.0 WebAPI on Local IIS with HTTPS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core-2.0

This is a requirement. Not asking for recommendation.

I have no problem with IIS Express. Also there is no problem with IIS and HTTP. 
My API is automatically added to 'Default Web Site' with HTTP bindings for HTTP case.

Had to add HTTPS manually however:

- created self-signed certificate
- added bindings with the certificate

After few attempts to run HTTPS from VS the bindings are automatically removed and I am getting error:
[Core20ErrorForHTTPS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DivT.png)

Is this possible on VS 2017 v. 15.4.2? If yes, then what am I doing wrong. If not then why.

Comment: VS has a "use HTTPS" check box, have you tried that?

Comment: You mean in project properties. It is for IIS Express and this works fine. There is no checkbox for IIS.